# How can i optimize below condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to check x and y values are undefined or empty. Following code working properly. but how can optimize this code.

```
if ((x == undefined || x == '') || (y == undefined || y == '')){
   z = false;
}else {
   z = true;
}
```

Comment: what about if x or y are `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
z = !((x == undefined || x == '') || (y == undefined || y == ''));
```

And if you are sure that the value of `x` and `y` would be either `undefined` or `string` then you can shrink your code like below,

```
z = !!(x || y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the way which I found. it can be extended for null check also.

```
z = !(x == undefined || x == '' || y== undefined || y=='')
```